# Need Assistance Solving Rails "bundle exec rake test" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hards. I am currently in the process of trying to learn *Rails* via https://www.railstutorial.org/book/ and am having a hard time figuring out what this error message in response to my `bundle exec rake test` command is trying to tell me to fix. I have looked all over the internet, contacted the author himself, and went back and tried to revise all of my code to no avail. I am super stuck and any help would be much appreciated. I've attached the code below. Thanks!

```
FAIL["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil", SessionsHelperTest, 2015-07-20 05:28:52 -0700]
     test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil#SessionsHelperTest (1437395332.13s)
            --- expected
            +++ actual
            @@ -1 +1 @@
            -#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", created_at: "2015-07-21 02:06:39", updated_at: "2015-07-21 02:06:40", password_digest: "$2a$04$Tz0wVFCkYN5YOCwpECJSNuKegIwy2hypnbIiCCAnvLA...", remember_digest: "$2a$04$RdGSm/cwWq.Jo3ljwRg0AePkqc7hoTFJ4Dind/jP1D8...">
            +nil
            test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the code being tested and the test code? We're programmers, not detectives ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is **not** an error message from `rake test`. It is the result of the test case you just ran using `bundle exec rake test`. In this case your test case failed because it is expecting a `User` object with `id=762146111` but got `nil` instead.

Based on the name of your test case *"test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil"*, I believe you will need to change your `current_user` method to return a `User` even when the session is `nil`.

You may find more information about Rails testing here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html